# custom text format scan with clamAV like SSN

Tags: clamav

As Clam supports ssn & its specific format of 9 digits. Can we test any custom format via regex or any pattern matching technology to this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get "test data" here

https://support.spirion.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000019252-Test-Sample-Data

And then test with clamav

```
wget http://www.identityfinder.com/software/KBFiles/110845/Identity_Finder_Test_Data.zip

unzip Identity_Finder_Test_Data.zip

clamscan -r --detect-structured=yes --structured-ssn-format=2 --structured-ssn-count=5 --structured-cc-count=5 Identity_Finder_Test_Data
```

You will see output such as ...

> **Identity_Finder_Test_Data/Employee Database.accdb: OK**
>   **Identity_Finder_Test_Data/Department.csv: Heuristics.Structured.SSN FOUND**
>
> output clipped at this point ...

"OK" means the data was valid, as far as clamav is concerned.

" Heuristics.Structured.SSN" means the data is "structured" or invalid.